# Error with Subscribe in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, subscribe

Im trying to fix this problem cause i can't login in my app.
I was following a youtube tutorial cause im new with angular.
This is the owner's github with his project ->
https://github.com/wesdoyle/base-chat/blob/master/src/app/services/chat.service.ts

It gives me the following error :

[image]

The code of **chat.service.ts** :

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase, FirebaseListObservable } from 'angularfire2/database';
import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { AuthService } from '../services/auth.service';
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';

import { ChatMessage } from '../models/chat-message.model';

@Injectable()
export class ChatService {
  user: firebase.User;
  chatMessages: FirebaseListObservable<ChatMessage[]>;
  chatMessage: ChatMessage;
  userName: Observable<string>;

  constructor(
    private db: AngularFireDatabase,
    private afAuth: AngularFireAuth
    ) {
        this.afAuth.authState.subscribe(auth => {
          if (auth !== undefined && auth !== null) {
            this.user = auth;
          }

          this.getUser().subscribe(a => {
            this.userName = a.displayName;
          });
        });
    }

  getUser() {
    const userId = this.user.uid;
    const path = `/users/${userId}`;
    return this.db.object(path);
  }

  getUsers() {
    const path = '/users';
    return this.db.list(path);
  }

  sendMessage(msg: string) {
    const timestamp = this.getTimeStamp();
    const email = this.user.email;
    this.chatMessages = this.getMessages();
    this.chatMessages.push({
      message: msg,
      timeSent: timestamp,
      userName: this.userName,
      email: email });
  }

  getMessages(): FirebaseListObservable<ChatMessage[]> {
    // query to create our message feed binding
    return this.db.list('messages', {
      query: {
        limitToLast: 25,
        orderByKey: true
      }
    });
  }

  getTimeStamp() {
    const now = new Date();
    const date = now.getUTCFullYear() + '/' +
                 (now.getUTCMonth() + 1) + '/' +
                 now.getUTCDate();
    const time = now.getUTCHours() + ':' +
                 now.getUTCMinutes() + ':' +
                 now.getUTCSeconds();

    return (date + ' ' + time);
  }
}
```

**user-list.components.ts** ->

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { User } from '../models/user.model';
import { ChatService } from '../services/chat.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-user-list',
  templateUrl: './user-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./user-list.component.css']
})
export class UserListComponent {
  users: User[];

  constructor(chat: ChatService) {
    chat.getUsers().subscribe(users => {
      this.users = users;
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: show me your UserList component as well, it's where the error is happening.

Comment: @GabrielBitencourt Done .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use **`this.chat`** instead of just chat inside the constructor

```
constructor(chat: ChatService) {
    this.chat.getUsers().subscribe(users => {
      this.users = users;
    });
  }
```

Comment: I added valuechanges(); and it seems that is fixed but only in one file.

Comment: you still have not answered my question! what is the error

Comment: Sorry, it generates a new error -> Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'AngularFireObject<{}>'. 

in chat.service.ts.

Comment: So should i leave valuechanges() ?

Comment: `return this.db.object(path);` is returning an `AngularFireObject`, not an `Observable`, so yes. Also, you should be defining return types for your functions like `getUser(): AngularFireObject<User> {` so your IDE can catch any errors early. (you'll need to import `User` at the top)

Answer (score 0):

Did you import `ChatService` in your **app.module.ts** file and add it to `providers`?

```
import { ChatService } from './services/chat.service';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ...
  ],
  imports: [
    ...
  ],
  providers: [
    ...
    ChatService
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

If so, try adding `private` before `chat` in your constructor.

```
constructor(private chat: ChatService) {
  chat.getUsers().subscribe(users => {
    this.users = users;
  });
}
```